# Low-frequency inverter power transformer selection

Tags: power, transformer, inverter

I'm currently designing a low-frequency inverter from 42 VDC to 220 VAC (effective) that goes up to 300 W.
The block diagram looks something like this:

[image]

This is the FFT before the filter:

[image]

As you can see I'm using the SPWM technique to draw a 50 Hz sinusoidal waveform by modulating the duty cycle.
The low-frequency transformer is then receiving a 50 Hz signal and a 16 kHz one.

The issue is that this is a low-frequency transformer, so the 16 kHz signal is causing some power losses in the iron core, resulting in a lower output voltage whenever a load is connected.

I present three possible solutions:

1. Filtering the 16 kHz component at the primary, before the transformer, with an LC low-pass filter. The downside is that whenever a load is connected this filter is very dissipative.
2. Using a high-frequency transformer. The downside of this is that for the 50 Hz signal this kind of transformers have fewer turns, so it's like a short-circuit.
3. Using a bigger low-frequency transformer. I don't really know why, but a bigger transformer performs great, without many losses.

I've tried (1) and (3), at the moment (3) is the best solution, but I don't really know about (2).

So my questions are:

Should I use a bigger low-frequency transformer? If so, how come a "bigger" transformer has less losses? How should I indicate this to the transformer manufacturer? Are there different ways of building iron laminated cores that "work better" with this setup?